# Table Rows have different input lengths

Tags: html, css

I am trying to layout a table (I know a grid might work better but do not feel like changing everything for the 3rd time).  I have 2 identical cells but one is smaller than the other.  No matter what I do, whether I create a smaller class, or make them equal one will always be bigger than another

```css
.grid td.normal{
    width: 100px;
}
.grid td.small{
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<tr>
            <!--Section Search-->
            <td colspan="1" class="normal">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <form name="r" action="section.php" method="get" class="form-labels-on-toptabletry">
                        <label><span>Section:</span><br></label>
                        <select name="section">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="0">Unknown</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value=8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="21">21</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                            <option value="23">23</option>
                            <option value="24">24</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="26">26</option>
                            <option value="27">27</option>
                            <option value="28">28</option>
                            <option value="29">29</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="31">31</option>
                            <option value="32">32</option>
                            <option value="33">33</option>
                            <option value="34">34</option>
                            <option value="35">35</option>
                            <option value="36">36</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-buttons">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
            <!--Township Search-->
            <td colspan="1" class="normal">
                <form name="township" action="township.php" method="get" class="form-labels-on-toptabletry">
                        <label><span>Township:</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="township"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-buttons">
                        </label>
                </form>
            </td>
            <!--TD Search-->
            <td colspan="1" class="normal">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <form name="r" action="td.php" method="get" class="form-labels-on-toptabletry">
                        <label>
                            <span>Township Direction:</span><br>
                            <select name="td">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="0">Unknown</option>
                                <option value="N">North</option>
                                <option value="S">South</option>
                            </select><br>
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-buttons">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
            <!--Range Search-->
            <td colspan="1" class="small">
                <form name="range" action="range.php" method="get" class="form-labels-on-toptabletry">
                        <label>
                            <span>Range:</span><br>
                            <input type="text" name="range"><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-buttons">
                        </label>
                    </form>
            </td>
            <!--RD Search-->
            <td colspan="1" class="normal">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <form name="rd" action="rd.php" method="get" class="form-labels-on-toptabletry">
                        <label><span>Range Direction:</span><br>
                            <select name="rd">
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                <option value="0">Unknown</option>
                                <option value="W">West</option>
                                <option value="E">East</option>
                            </select><br>
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-buttons">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

On the snippet it looks ok but here is what it looks like when I test it:
[Different Size Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHFFi.png)
Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: 100px is not big enough to hold an input, so the table extends the width of the td to contain it.

Comment: aaaa so the smallest I can go for an input is 100px?  I did not know that, thanks for the information